# Typo in question statment

Tags: discussion

I just posted a question last night and someone provided a valid answer, but there was a typo in the question statement. So, although the solution is perfect for the question I asked, it is not for the question I *intended* to ask.

Should I just edit the question or accept the answer and ask again, this time with the correc statement?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for asking. $ $

Comment: +1 For self-referential post (see typo in title)

Comment: @MattN. That's hilarious, my bad.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is better not to edit the question in a way that makes existing answers wrong.

Ask another question.

Comment: But make sure to link each question to the other, and explain what you are doing, so people can see what is going on, and so your question doesn't get closed as a duplicate by people who remember the earlier version and overlook the difference.